# java code to use timestamp items inside a loop

Tags: java, jdbc

```
ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT starttime FROM user_req ORDER BY req_id ASC LIMIT 1");
Timestamp a;
while (rs2.next()) {
    a = rs2.getTimestamp("starttime");

    System.out.println(a);
    long t=a.getTime();
    long m=5*60*1000;

    Timestamp b= new Timestamp(t+m);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

This code produces two timestamps: `2013-12-12 09:00:00` and `2013-12-12 09:05:00`.

In this code I get two timestamp items one with adding 5 min to the previous one, can anyone pls help me out in how to put it in a for loop such that it should start wd the "timestamp a" till "timestamp b" and it should increment with 1 minute, so that I can perform roundrobin code in it. please help me how to iterate over the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
for(long current = a ; current <= a+5*60*1000 ; current += 60*1000) {
    // do something with current
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
long starTime=a.getTime();
long endTime=starTime+5*60*1000;

for (long currTime = starTime; currTime < endTime; currTime += 60*1000) {
   // Do your stuff, currTime will increment in 1 minute steps
}
```